# Sum of even numbers not equals to each other

Tags: python

Need help for a task. I should to sum even numbers not equal to each other, for example I have a list of ints like `[1, 3, 2, 2, 4]` the output should be `6`, and if a list all numbers are the same it should sum only 2 numbers, for instance `[2, 2, 2, 2]` it should print out `4` but I don't understand how to check the equality of the numbers in a loop:

```
a = [int(x) for x in input().split()]

for i in a:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            summ += i
        elif i == i:
            continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many methods , Here are two methods :

First one , using dict , dict key can't be same so just assign the value as keys in dict and it will be unique :

```
output={j:i for i,j in enumerate(data) if j%2==0}
```

And then just boolean condition :

```
print([sum(output),sum(list(map(lambda x:x+x,output)))][len(output)==1])
```

How does this condition work?

booleans are a subclass of int , so [len(output)==1] produce a integer value but ['false','true'] takes it as index value.

output:

```
6
```

If same values as you said then you want two number sum in this condition:

```
data=[2,2,2,2]
```

output:

```
4
```

Second one using the set:

```
data=[4,4,4,4]

def even_(data):
    sum_data=[]
    for i in data:
        if i%2==0:
            sum_data.append(i)
    if len(set(sum_data)) == 1:
        return list(map(lambda x: x + x, set(sum_data)))[0]
    else:
        return sum(set(sum_data))

print(even_(data))
```

output:

```
6
```

Comment: This code also doesn't work with a list with the same numbers.

Comment: @Bootuz I didn't see that second case, fixed it, Now check.

Comment: I'm inclined to -1 just for use of "boolean indexing" instead of using a ternary `... if ... else ...`. And why do you use a dict instead of the much-simpler set, and why `map` each `x` to `x+x` instead of just multiplying the sum with 2?

Answer (score 5):

Don't use a loop to check for duplicates. Instead, [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sum) the numbers after putting them into a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#func-set).

```
>>> lst = [1, 3, 2, 2, 4]
>>> sum(x for x in set(lst) if x % 2 == 0)
6
```

If you only want to filter out consecutive equal numbers, you could "collapse" those ranges with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> lst = [1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2]
>>> sum(k for k, g in itertools.groupby(lst) if k % 2 == 0)
8  # last 2 after 4 is counted
```

---

> and if a list all numbers are the same it should sum only 2 numbers

I still believe this to be a misunderstanding of the task or a mistake in the given example, but if this is *really* the desired behaviour, you can, again, convert the list to a set and see if the set has only one element, and in this case take the sum times two.

```
>>> lst = [2, 2, 2, 2]
>>> sum(x for x in set(lst) if x % 2 == 0) * (2 if len(set(lst)) == 1 else 1)
4
>>> lst = [1, 3, 2, 2, 4]
>>> sum(x for x in set(lst) if x % 2 == 0) * (2 if len(set(lst)) == 1 else 1)
6
```

The first part of this expression is the same as above, and the second part is a ternary that returns the factor 1 or 2 depending on the size of the set.

Comment: it won't work if I'll have a list with numbers all equal like `[2, 2, 2]`

Comment: @Bootuz Why not? What's the expected sum then?

Comment: the expected sum is 4

Comment: @Bootuz Thought so, but why? By what reasoning?

Comment: Why would `[2, 2, 2]` outputs `4` ?

Comment: by condition of the task

Comment: @Bootuz Could you explain that condition in, like, two or three sentences? It's really, _really_ not clear.

Comment: The condition is: "You need to write a program that reads from the standard input N of integers, computes the only ones (by value) among them, and outputs it to standard output." and then it says: `Sample Input 1: 2 2 2` and `Sample Output 1: 4` and so on.

Comment: @Bootuz That does not make any sense. I'd assume that there is a mistake in the assignment. You might ask your advisor or whomever you got that task from. Or do _you_ have any explanation _why_ it should give 4 in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I have missed this part of your question:

> if a list all numbers are the same it should sum only 2 numbers, for
>   instance [2, 2, 2, 2] it should print out 4

To do that you can simply add an if else structure such as:

```
if len(set(a))==1 and not a[0]%2:
    print(a[0]*2)
else: 
    pass
    #any approach below
```

Try to use amazint Python data structures =)

In my example I have created a set of numbers so that we can sum up only unique values.

```
a = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
print(sum({num for num in a if not num%2}))
```

Also hidden conversion to bool is used in `if not num%2`

In addition you cat use more clear solution. Little bit improved version of your answer:

```
a = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
summ=0
filt_set = set()
for num in a:
    if not num%2 and num not in filt_set:
        filt_set.add(num)
        summ+=num
print(summ)
```

It uses set as more effective data structure then a list when we talk about searching an element. Also it sums elements at the same time with adding them to the set.

During the discussion in comments I realized that you may need a code to sum up only non-duplicated numbers, not unique ones. I suggest to use functional Python features:

```
from collections import Counter

summ = sum(map(lambda x: x[0]
        ,filter(lambda x:x[1]==1 
                ,Counter(a).items())))

print(summ)
```

So that here for `a = [1, 3, 2, 2, 4]` we will get 1+3+4 = 8.

Also you can achieve it in a more traditional way:

```
elt_set = set() # a set to keep info about elements
res_set = set() # a set that we will sum up

for e in a:
# if the element happens for the first time, add it to the res_set
if e not in elt_set:
    res_set.add(e)
else if e in res_set:
# if it has been already seen before, remove it from the res_set
    res_set.remove(e)
elt_set.add(e)

print(sum(res_set))
```

Comment: it doesn't work if a list contains all numbers equal to each other, for example [2, 2, 2, 2] your code prints out 2, but by the condition of the task it should be 4.

Comment: @Bootuz it should be equal to 2 if you need to sum up unique numbers or 0 if you need to sum numbers that have no duplicates in a series. How can you obtain 4?

Comment: Nice idea, using `Counter`, but IMHO would be more readable using a comprehension instead of `map` and `filter`: `sum(x for x, c in Counter(a).items() if c == 1)`

Comment: Agree. I also like comprehensions more then functional tools =) I will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is :

```
lst = [1, 3, 2, 2, 4]

exists = []
total = 0
for nb in lst:
    # if nb is even AND has not been used yet...
    if nb % 2 == 0 and nb not in exists:
        total += nb
        # check the nb as used.
        exists.append(nb)
```